# how to give complete controller's path in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a variable in javascript as follows which works fine.

```
var url = http://example.com/directory_name/
```

above link returns json data which I later on display it using javascript.
But what I want is to give a complete path to a controller and then name of the function like following

```
http://example.com/directory_name/api/v1/ //whereas api is controller's name and v1 function inside this controller
```

how can I achieve this?

**Update**

Here is my code for controller

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    //$this->load->view('api');
    $this->v1('api');
}

public function v1 () {
    //$this->load->view('api');
    echo site_url();
    $arr = array(
      array(
        'id' => 15642,
        'title' => 'title one',
        'description' => 'this is description for title one'
      ),
      array(
        'id' => 15643,
        'title' => 'title two',
        'description' => 'this is description for title two'
      ),
      array(
        'id' => 15644,
        'title' => 'title Three',
        'description' => 'this is description for title Three. this is description for title Three. this is description for title Three.'
      )
    );

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is JS

```
init: function (jokesContainer) {
            container = container;
            url       = 'http://example.com/directory/api/v1';    
            Get.get(url, container);
        }
```

**Update 3**

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase chrome_web_apps

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You want to write the full site/controller/action path at your php file ?

Comment: I want to give a full path in javascript url variable.

Comment: So /directory/api/v1 doesn't work ? Do you have Routers set up-ed

Comment: Have you made any Routes at your router? (copy it)

Comment: This is all what I have in my routes `$route['default_controller'] = "api";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: ok and have you set uped htaccess rewrite rules?

Comment: No I haven't write those. How can I do that?

Comment: create .htaccess file where is your index.php  and use the code which I add at my answer

Comment: You mean index.php which is inside application folder?

Comment: No the one which is out of app/sys folders

Comment: It does not work. When I use url with index.php then it works otherwise it does not.

Comment: with empty index_page it doesnt works ? Its not possible if it works with index.php and you remove index_page it 100% have to work without that index.php at the url

Comment: Not working no idea why.

Comment: Its possible that your server doesn't allow htaccess file in subfolders or at all .. I don't know how are your settings so I can't answer you 100% sure.

Comment: I changed your htaccess file abit but now I am getting Internal server error. Let me post my latest htaccess

Comment: Now see my latest updates above

Comment: RewriteBase chrome_web_apps
 What is that rewrite base ? usually its only .. 
RewriteBase /

Comment: to me it seems apache rewrite module is not enabled how can I check it on?

Comment: put that folder >  /chrome_web_apps/
For apache rewrite find in apache config folder your config file and search for "rewrite"

Comment: It gives me this error then `Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.` I am using a live server so how can I access apache's httpd.conf

Comment: can you provide me some link ..

Comment: here is a link http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/

Comment: This way is not working http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/api/v1

Comment: and if you set Rewritebase /
without folder ?

Comment: Then I get this error `Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file. `

Comment: add at your config.php base_url > http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/

Comment: this htaccess is inside the joks folder or at main ?

Comment: http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/index.php/api/v1

This works.. soo please check again the config.php as I described in my answer

Comment: If I set default_controller then still this link does not work: http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/index.php/api/v1 without index.php

Comment: Did you set index_page = empty at config.php ?

Comment: yes i did but still not working.

Comment: Ok at http://zafarsaleem.info/joks/api/v1 I am redirected to your main  and this isn't comming from the CI .. check if you have set somewhere redirections at your main site htaccess or something else..

Comment: No Idea why it been redirected to my main site.

Answer (score 2):

1st. Creating rewrite rules: Set this code into .htaccess file at your main folder where is the main index.php out of app/sys folders.

This is important so your links to work other way you will be able to load only the main page..

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

*Note that your server MUST ACCEPT HTACCESS files so that can work..

2nd. Remove the index.php from your CI urls.
At

```
app/config/config.php
```

find and set to empty

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3rd. To generate correct urls use that CI php function

```
site_url("api/v1");
```

It requires url Helper
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: I don't want to use any php code in javascript. Since I make that link public so all I want for users to copy that entire link and use it.

Comment: To show it to users you have to generate it.. 
And you can do that via your PHP code ..

Comment: @al0neevenings site_url .. which I added at my answer

Comment: OK. Where will I add site_url() method? In controller or where?

Comment: How to tell you when I don't have your code ? ..
Add it at your View file if you want ..

Comment: Here is my directory structure: I have one view file and one controller with class name `Api` which consists of two methods `index()` and `v1()`. And inside `v1()` function I am simply generating an array and echoing with json_encode(). Thats all what I have.

Comment: ok just where you set this
var url = http://example.com/directory_name/ set it with this function site_url('')